# Enums and Template Methods

Tags: java, enums

Enum is basically a special class type, and can have methods and fields just like any other class. Any one know about the Enums Template Methods. Please give a real example for Template Methods on Enums. And can you explain about Enum Reverse Lookups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Java 5.0 Enum tricks](http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2007/java/making-the-most-of-java-50-enum-tricks), specially have a look on the video.

Here is a simple example of a "command" enumeration:

```
public enum Toy {
     DOLL() {
          @Override public void execute() { 
               System.out.println("I'm a doll."); 
          }
     },
     SOLDIER() {
          @Override public void execute() { 
               System.out.println("I'm a soldier."); 
          }
     };
     //template method
     public abstract void execute();
}
```

Here objects Doll and Soldier both have a different implementation of the function `execute()`.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the "Template Method" design pattern, one can create enumerations that are factories or command objects, but a defined set of objects. Here is a simple [example of a "command" enumeration:](http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2007/java/making-the-most-of-java-50-enum-tricks)

you will also get explanation of Enum Reverse Lookups over the above link