# Avoid boolean flags as an attribute

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring, boolean

First of all I wanna say I don't have much experience in refactoring and don't know if this is off-topic.

I'm working with given code where a lot of boolean attributes are used, which I would like to avoid because of readability, and I don't know how to handle it in a proper way.

```
class MyClass(){
    boolean a;
    ...
    void function(){
        ...
        a = true;
        ...
    }

    void anotherFunction(){
        ...
        if(a == true){
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The `boolean a` is used in multiple `function`s like this, where `anotherFunction`s are running the code regarding to `a`. This is tough to understand the code and the dependencies and furthermore hard for me to refactor it, because of the use of multiple attributes and local variables in `anotherFunction`. The effort to refactor this could be very high imo.

I always tried to avoid the use of a boolean like this, because in my eyes its not good practice. If I'm wrong don't hesitate to correct me.

Now I would like to know if I should refactor the code and spend the effort? Is there some kind of pattern which could be used in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the state pattern. Encapsulate the state and behavior depending on the boolean variable in a separate abstract `State` class. When the boolean is set to false, change the state to an instance of `FalseState` (which extends `State`), and delegate to this `FalseState` instance. When the boolean is set to true, change the state to an instance of `TrueState`, and delegate to this `TrueState` instance.

For example, the following class

```
public class Apple {

    private boolean fresh = false;

    public String getColor() {
        if (fresh) {
            return "green";
        }
        else {
            return "brown";
        }
    }

    public void setFresh(boolean fresh) {
        this.fresh = fresh;
    }
}
```

could be refactored to

```
public class Apple {

    private AppleState state = new OldAppleState();

    public String getColor() {
        return state.getColor();
    }

    public void setFresh(boolean fresh) {
        this.state = state.nextState(fresh);
    }

    private static abstract class State {
        public abstract State nextState(boolean fresh);
        public abstract String getColor();
    }

    private static class OldAppleState extends State{
        public State nextState(boolean fresh) {
            return fresh ? new FreshAppleState() : this;
        }
        public String getColor() {
            return "brown";
        }
    }


    private static class FreshAppleState extends State{
        public State nextState(boolean fresh) {
            return fresh ? this : new OldAppleState();
        }
        public String getColor() {
            return "green";
        }
    }
}
```

I used inner classes, but you could of course use top-level classes.

Comment: This is really nice to define different states. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

If the boolean a is used multiple times, I prefer monad-like inner class functions.

```
public class BoolAHandler{
    public bool A = false;
    public BoolAHandler IfTrue(Action act){
        if(A){
            act();
        }
        return this;
    }
    public BoolAHandler IfFalse(Action act){
        if(!A){
            act();
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
boolAHandler.IfTrue( () => { doFunctionA(); } )
            .IfFalse( () => { doFunctionB(); } );
```

Of course, if the boolean a has meaning, you can adjust it to the meaning too. Say that if it handle published state, you can change `IfTrue` to `IfAlreadyPublished` and `IfFalse` to `IfNotPublished`.

Comment: Never heard of monad before. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

The code sample you give is obviously somewhat truncated, but it sounds to me like this class is behaving like a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

If you have many boolean attributes within the class, and they all determine the behaviour of methods within that function, you very quickly end up with an explosion of possibilities, and the code can become hard to follow - you end up with code like:

```
if (true == a && false == b){
   ...
}
elseif (false == a && false == b){
   ....
}
```

and so on.

The first refactoring you can apply is to create a state lookup method; this converts the code above to:

```
if (aNotB == getState(a, b)){
   ....
}
elseif (notANotB == getState(a, b)){
   ...
}
```

This makes the code a little easier, and forces you to think in terms of the state of the application, not individual booleans.

You can then go to a full state machine if you need to - there are reference implementations all over the interwebs for most programming languages.

Comment: Yeah the possible combinations to define a state are really annoying!

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about the logic in terms of state transition IS crucial. I'd go a step further to cleanly define your states using enums.

```
public enum AppState { 
    ST1(false, false), 
    ST2(false, true),
    ST3(true, false), 
    ST4(true, true);
    private Boolean x, y;
}
```

One particularly useful advantage of using enums is the ability to define template methods - [Template methods using enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799936/enums-and-template-methods). Will let you streamline your functionality to match your state and make it more object-oriented.

Comment: Defining states as enums sounds nice to me.